# Sitefinity Invalid Root

Tags: .net, sitefinity

I had lost access to the database, after this incident I reset the password of the database from the control panel; to view an error saying that the connection to the database is incorrect. I followed some research and found out the data connection credentials is found in the DataConfig file. Upon that case I went to that file through FTP and directly edited accordingly with the new username and password.

The following error showed up:

```
    Server Error in '/' Application.
Invalid root node configured for pages. No root node with the name of "f669d9a7-009d-4d83-ddaa-000000000002".
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Invalid root node configured for pages. No root node with the name of "f669d9a7-009d-4d83-ddaa-000000000002".

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[ConfigurationErrorsException: Invalid root node configured for pages. No root node with the name of "f669d9a7-009d-4d83-ddaa-000000000002".]
   Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.SiteMapBase.Initialize(String name, NameValueCollection attributes) +2778
   System.Web.Configuration.ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProvider(ProviderSettings providerSettings, Type providerType) +597
   System.Web.Configuration.ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProviders(ProviderSettingsCollection configProviders, ProviderCollection providers, Type providerType) +118
   System.Web.Configuration.SiteMapSection.get_ProvidersInternal() +130
   System.Web.SiteMap.Initialize() +226
   System.Web.SiteMap.get_Providers() +4
   Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.SiteMapBase.GetSiteMapProvider(String rootName) +145
   Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.SiteMapProviderResolver.GetSiteMapProviderForAppRelativeUrl(String url) +111
   Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.SiteMapProviderResolver.GetSiteMapProviderForRequest(HttpContextBase context) +48
   Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.SitefinityRoute.GetSiteMapProvider() +39
   Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.SitefinityRoute.GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext) +89
   System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection.GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext) +233
   System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.PostResolveRequestCache(HttpContextBase context) +60
   System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.OnApplicationPostResolveRequestCache(Object sender, EventArgs e) +82
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +136
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

I have been trying for a couple of days yet its not working.

Answer (score 1):

From this [thread](http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/deployment--/invalid-root-node-configured-for-pages-no-root-node-with-the-name-of-frontendsitemap-error#Hk64csE3622pWP8AAERlJg) it looks like it could be an issue with your database user not having their default schema set to dbo. Also, make sure that your user has db_owner permissions set.

Hope that helps!